# Lubuntu 15.04 Missing Libnl1

Tags: upgrade, libraries, 15.04

Been trying to install Libnl1, airodump-ng calls for it. A program I use often. I'e tried the standard "apt-get install libnl1" but it is not found in the updated repositories

Comment: Post the output of `apt-cache policy airodump-ng` in your question.

Comment: gregory@gregory-lubuntu:~$ apt-cache policy aircrack-ng
aircrack-ng:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:1.2-0~beta3-4
  Version table:
     1:1.2-0~beta3-4 0
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/universe amd64 Packages

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu/Lubuntu 15.04 airodump-ng is provided by the package aircrack-ng from the default Ubuntu repositories. To install it open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install aircrack-ng
```

The dependency for aircrack-ng in Lubuntu 15.04 is not called libnl1, instead it is libnl-3-200.

Comment: Here you go +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer, I just needed to build from source again. I was using 1.2 RC2,so installing from apt-get wasn't helping me. Karel was correct in the dependency change, but after my upgrade I still had the compiled binary for 14.10. Thanks for all your help guys!

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe this is included in another package. Try opening a Terminal window (`Ctrl + Alt + T`) and simply run:

```
libnl1
```

It will say something like *Could not find this command*, but if libnl1 is included in another package it will say *but you can get it by running certain command*.

Try it and come tell us what you got.